# Given points $p$ and $q$ in the plane, find all points $z$ such that $\triangle pqz$ has at least one $60^\circ$ angle

Tags: geometry

> Say that we have two points in the plane $p$, $q$. I need to find geometrically 
>   $$\{z\in\mathbb{R}^2 : \triangle pqz \text{ has at least one $60^\circ$ angle}\}$$

I want there to be lines in this locus (so that for a seperate problem I can apply the Szemeredi-Trotter theorem), but for some reason I can only find rays. I am doing something wrong or are there actually only rays?

Comment: There are two circumference arcs having $pq$ as end-points formed by the cases in which the angle at $z$ is $60$ degrees. Then there are $4$ lines, $2$ passing through $p$ and $2$ from $q$ forming angles $60$ with the secment $pq$, for the cases in which the angles at $p$ or at $q$ are $60$. So, the locus is the union of those

Comment: Would you mind drawing it out and posting an answer?

Comment: As @user647486 notes, the locus consists of four rays and two circular arcs, not lines or circles. This is because requiring a $60^\circ$ *interior* angle is a somewhat artificial constraint. If the requirement were loosened to also allow for $60^\circ$ *exterior* angles (equivalently, if at least one pair of lines $\overleftrightarrow{pq}$, $\overleftrightarrow{pz}$, $\overleftrightarrow{zq}$ make a $60^\circ$ angle), then the locus would consist of two lines and two circles.

Answer (score 1):

This is the picture ($p$ and $q$ are excluded from the locus):

[image]